# JUMBLE WORDS ,I want that if once the word is asked to any player should not repeat

Tags: python-3.x, list, visual-studio, solver, solution

**I dont want to reapt the word once aksed with one player**

### i am creating jumble words game but the proble is the word once used are repeating again and again so what should i do to avoid it

please explain what to do
i tried using del also but it did not worked out ,also i tried all pop but still unable to excute
kindly suggest

```
import random
def choose():
    words=["rainbow","computer","science","mathmatics","player","condition","water","reverse","board","education","sharemarket","mango","magnum","mirchi"]
    pick=random.choice(words)   #to choose random words we have used random library
   
     
    return pick
def jumble(word):
    jumbled="".join(random.sample(word,len(word))) #join function is used to join words together,also random.sample word
    return jumbled    #randmoly select the word 
def thank(p1name,p2name,points_p1,points_p2):
    print(p1name,"your score is :", points_p1)
    print(p2name,"your score is :", points_p2)
    print("THANKS FOR PLAYING\n Have a nice day!!!!!!!")
def play():
    p1name=input("player 1, Please enter your name  ")
    p2name=input("player 2, Please enter your name  ")
    points_p1=0
    points_p2=0
    turn=0
    while(1):
        #computer will give question to players picked words
        
        picked_word=choose()
        #now create the question
        Q=jumble(picked_word)
        print(Q)
        #PLAYER 1
        if turn%2==0:
            print(p1name,"your turn. ")
            answer=input("What's in your mind\n")
            if answer==picked_word:
                points_p1=points_p1+1
                print("your score is :" , points_p1)
                
            else:
                print("better luck next time", picked_word)
                c=int(input("press 1 to continue and 0 to quit"))
                if c==0:
                    thank(p1name,p2name,points_p1,points_p2)
                    break
        #player 2
        else:
            print(p2name,"your turn. ")
            answer=input("What's in your mind\n")
            if answer==picked_word:
                points_p2=points_p2+1
                print("your score is :" , points_p2)
            else:
                print("better luck next time", picked_word)
                c=int(input("press 1 to continue and 0 to quiet  "))
                if c==0:
                    thank(p1name,p2name,points_p1,points_p2)
                    break
        turn=turn+1


play()
```

Comment: check out `random.shuffle()`

Answer (score 0):

To not repeat words add below code. It will maintain a list of already chosen words so far and if it's already used then it will again go to choose till it gets unused word.

```
def play():
    p1name = input("player 1, Please enter your name  ")
    p2name = input("player 2, Please enter your name  ")
    points_p1 = 0
    points_p2 = 0
    turn = 0
    chosen_words = []
    while (1):
        # computer will give question to players picked words

        while (1):
            picked_word = choose()
            if picked_word in chosen_words:
                pass
            else:
                chosen_words.append(picked_word)
                break

        # now create the question
        Q = jumble(picked_word)
        print(Q)
```

word not repeated once asked to any player

Output:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 193.6494.30)
player 1, Please enter your name  Pooja
player 2, Please enter your name  Meera
rchimi
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
mirchi
your score is : 1
ecnscie
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
science
your score is : 1
ayeprl
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
player
your score is : 2
stcithmmaa
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
mathmatics
your score is : 2
mharreeakts
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
sharemarket
your score is : 3
waret
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
water
your score is : 3
noiitcdno
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
condition
your score is : 4
ndiueocta
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
education
your score is : 4
gammun
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
magnum
your score is : 5
uertocpm
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
computer
your score is : 5
servere
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
reverse
your score is : 6
nogma
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
mango
your score is : 6
iraownb
Pooja your turn. 
What's in your mind
rainbow
your score is : 7
abdor
Meera your turn. 
What's in your mind
board
your score is : 7
```